# import csv data to sql without rounding

Tags: csv, rounding

I have large csv data that needs to be imported to a table. I want all data from source to be loaded without rounding. How can i enforce  my rule on the destination table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the exact value of data from the source, I will change the data type of the destination column to real, float and decimal one test at a time. Since the goal is to protect the integrity of the data I will have to go back and forth to make sure that the data is intact at the destination table. Then I will check the maximum value of the data after the decimal point using the following query.

select MyData, patindex('%.%',reverse(replace(rtrim(replace(convert(varchar(100),MyData),'0',' ')),' ','0')))-1
from MyTabel
order by 2 desc

The query above will give me the (largest to smallest) number of significant digit after decimal point. Based on this information I will decide what will be the appropriate column data type.